# Keystone Error - You cannot update populated relationships

Tags: javascript, mongoose, keystonejs

I have created a model

```
newProject = new Project.model({

    licensee:           req.query.licensee ? req.query.licensee : '',
    webUrl:             req.query.webUrl ? req.query.webUrl : '',
    appName:            req.query.appName ? req.query.appName : '',
    licenseDesktop:     req.query.cart.license.desktop.quantity ? req.query.cart.license.desktop.quantity : '',
    licenseDesktopLabel:req.query.cart.license.desktop.label ? req.query.cart.license.desktop.label : '',
    licenseWeb:         req.query.cart.license.web.quantity ? req.query.cart.license.web.quantity : '',
    licenseWebLabel:    req.query.cart.license.web.label ? req.query.cart.license.web.label : '',
    licenseApp:         req.query.cart.license.app.quantity ? req.query.cart.license.app.quantity : '',
    licenseAppLabel:    req.query.cart.license.app.label ? req.query.cart.license.app.label : '',
    collections:        req.query.cart.collections,
    pairs:              req.query.cart.pairs,
    fonts:              req.query.cart.fonts,
    downloadName:       downloadName,
    fileCreated:        false
});
```

That seems correctly structured

```
{ 
    licensee: 'wer',
    webUrl: '',
    appName: '',
    mindate: 0,
    fileCreated: 'false',
    cost: 0,
    downloadName: 'wer-68201706172956354',
    fonts: 
     [ { _id: 55945f1e67c1b9371e2b1241,
             __v: 0,
             createdAt: Wed Jul 01 2015 14:43:58 GMT-0700 (PDT),
             createdBy: 558c02e92e1093453a504a0e,
             description: '',
             slug: 'fort-thin',
             sortOrder: 14,
             title: 'Fort Thin',
             tokens: [],
             trackingAmount: '',
             trackingChange: '',
             typefaceName: 'Fort',
             updatedAt: Sun Jul 03 2016 10:28:35 GMT-0700 (PDT),
             updatedBy: 55df7e156bee0c7728109df9,
             weightName: 'Thin',
             price: 50,
             sell: true,
             style: 'Normal',
             weight: '100',
             otfFile: [Object],
             ttfFile: [Object],
             eotFile: [Object],
             woffFile: [Object],
             onHomepage: 'show' },
         { _id: 55c073bfe490ca292ae80814,
             __v: 0,
             createdAt: Tue Aug 04 2015 01:11:43 GMT-0700 (PDT),
             createdBy: 558c02e92e1093453a504a0e,
             description: '',
             slug: 'fort-thin-italic',
             sortOrder: 15,
             title: 'Fort Thin Italic',
             tokens: [],
             trackingAmount: '',
             trackingChange: '',
             typefaceName: 'Fort',
             updatedAt: Sun Jul 03 2016 10:28:56 GMT-0700 (PDT),
             updatedBy: 55df7e156bee0c7728109df9,
             weightName: 'Thin',
             price: 50,
             sell: true,
             style: 'Italic',
             weight: '100',
             otfFile: [Object],
             ttfFile: [Object],
             eotFile: [Object],
             woffFile: [Object],
             onHomepage: 'show' } ],
    pairs: 
     [ { _id: 574dfc9a7c2cb9a32819d2b1,
             __v: 1,
             createdAt: Tue May 31 2016 14:05:30 GMT-0700 (PDT),
             createdBy: 55df7e156bee0c7728109df9,
             slug: 'fort-thins',
             sortOrder: 3,
             title: 'Fort Thins',
             titleStyle: 55945f1e67c1b9371e2b1241,
             updatedAt: Tue May 31 2016 14:08:21 GMT-0700 (PDT),
             updatedBy: 55df7e156bee0c7728109df9,
             price: 75,
             sell: true,
             fonts: [Object],
             autoStyle: true } ],
    collections: [],
    licenseAppLabel: '0 applications',
    licenseApp: '0',
    licenseWebLabel: '0 visitors / month',
    licenseWeb: '0',
    licenseDesktopLabel: 'Up to 3 computers',
    licenseDesktop: '1',
    _id: 5935f784c69f58a58003ff6c 
}
```

but when I run

```
var updater = newProject.getUpdateHandler(req, res, {

        errorMessage: 'There was an error creating your new project.'
    });

updater.process(req.body, {

    flashErrors: true,
    logErrors: true
}, function(err) {

    if (err) {

        console.log("There was an error updating your account. ");
    }
    next();
});
```

I receive an error (Error: fieldTypes.relationship.updateItem() Error - You cannot update populated relationships.)

It seems to fire on newProject.getUpdateHandler. I can't seem to get around this error, I'm using keystone 4.0, does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to resolve the issue.. but I feel like it isn't the correct answer.

```
newProject.save(function(err) {

    if (err) {

        logError(err, "There was an error updating your account. ");
    }
    next();
});
```